# Regarding entry into the Schengen area from a port different to the country that issued my Schengen visa

Tags: visas, schengen

My Schengen visa has been issued from the Netherlands, however I am planning to enter the Schengen region from Latvia. I am planning to carry my travel itinerary that states that I will be in the Netherlands for the longest period, proof of funds and train itinerary (As I am planning to travel internally via train). However, I have no PURCHASED/ CONFIRMED tickets that show my travel to Netherlands, as I am planning to buy the Eurail pass once I enter the Schengen region.
I just want to know whether this information is enough to enter through country that is not the country that issued my visa and if I have to have confirmed tickets to prove that I am travelling to the Netherlands? I'm scared that they will deny entry at the border, and I just want to make sure I have everything in order.
Thank you very much!

Comment: I assume you will be flying from Latvia to the Netherlands? In that case show your plane ticket. Also I suggest you reconsider getting an Eurail Pass.

Comment: @KristvanBesien OP mentions using rail, not flying, as mode of transport. Some people travel by rail because they want to travel by rail, that being an important part of their trip.

Comment: From Latvia to the Netherlands there are however no convenient rail routes.

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure you want to use a rail pass, consider buying it online before your travel.
Also get some seat reservations for trains you want to use.

Or, and this may well be cheaper, buy tickets for your trains, for specific dates and times. You lose the flexibility of a rail pass but get surety for immigration at the border instead.

If you are no rail fan, a flight to Amsterdam will likely be cheaper, faster and more enjoyable.

Just your plans and itinerary should be enough for immigration, seat reservations and/or tickets for the trains make your plans stronger.

Answer (score 0):

It is generally best practice to first enter the country issuing the visa, but authorities in Latvia will likely be more relaxed than if the situation were reversed (entering NL on LV visa).

I do strongly suggest that you buy your Eurail pass BEFORE your trip as it will be considerably cheaper and there are also some options you can only purchase while outside of Europe.

Latvia, along with other Baltic countries, is not included in a Eurail pass. Rail travel between Baltics and the rest of Europe is technically possible, but is slow, uncomfortable, and no less expensive than travel by bus or even air.

The closest point of entry to the Eurail system from Latvia is Warsaw, Poland.

If you wish to travel from Riga and explore nearby countries, for example Lithuania, I suggest to travel by bus, same with to Warsaw.

I would recommend to travel with:

https://luxexpress.eu/en

Comment: Daniel, do you have any ties with that website? It is allowed to mention a site you own but be careful, commercial links are often seen as spam.

Comment: I have nothing to do with any travel company. I have lived in multiple countries, travel a lot, across a number of countries, and have opinions on providers I trust. I've been traveling about 200 days a year for many years, so, have a lot of insights. I discovered this site and simply thought to share, but this admin/editing policy is actually not all that welcoming.